# "MuleESB: File Transport" does it support reading pdf files.

Tags: mule

I have a use case that requires exposing data read from a pdf file over a web-service post some transformation.The available Mule documentation does not list the supported file types.

Thanks,
Wajid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File inbound and outbound endpoints are file type agnostic so you can read or write any type of file.

Comment: Thanks for replying back. I am new to Mule. Would be great if you could give me some pointers on a possible approach.

Comment: You can read any file on demand using the Mule Client: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18642271/387927